# CherryPy don't listen for SIGHUP // daemonize CherryPy script

Tags: python, signals, ubuntu-16.04, daemon, cherrypy

I've developed a Telegram Bot with the CherryPy framework, and am trying to deploy it on an EC2 instance.

Since my python script isn't a daemon, CherryPy seems to shut it down when it receives SIGHUP (my Terminal closes). I don't want this to happen, and there seems to be a way to modify how CherryPy handles these Signals:

From [docs](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/_modules/cherrypy/process/plugins.html):

> You can modify what signals your application listens for, and what it
>   does
>       when it receives signals, by modifying :attr:`SignalHandler.handlers`,
>       a dict of {signal name: callback} pairs. The default set is::
>
> ```
>     handlers = {'SIGTERM': self.bus.exit,
>                 'SIGHUP': self.handle_SIGHUP,
>                 'SIGUSR1': self.bus.graceful}
> ```

My current script has a `cherrypy.config.update()` with the relevant server configuration dictionary, and a `cherrypy.server.quickstart()`. Can I also make it not handle the signals?

Or should I just deploy my script as a daemon? If so, how can I do it native to Ubuntu?

Comment: I would recommend you to use a production ready WSGI server in production. See https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/deploy.html#wsgi-servers .

Comment: @uphill that doesn't really solve my problem of wanting the script run continuously.

Comment: True, but the wsgi server supports running continuously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CherryPy ships with a built-in daemonizer, sandwich the calls between your config update and `quickstart` like so:

```
cherrypy.config.update(...)

cherrypy.process.plugins.Daemonizer(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()
cherrypy.process.plugins.SignalHandler(cherrypy.engine).subscribe()

cherrypy.quickstart(...)
```

Another option you might consider would be to run your server behind a process controller like Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/)